# How to make this query get some data from another table in reverse order

Tags: mysql, select

hi actually i have a query that work pretty fine this is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `post_roomid` = '$room' AND post_id > '$last' AND user_id != $uid" ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 60) AS log 
ORDER BY `post_id` ASC
```

it actually work but i do not understand how to make a join with this query and keep the inverted order of post

i need to retreive some data from user table where user_id from user_table will fit user_id from chat table but i need to keep the result in same order

thanks for help

Comment: Post some sample data and your expected result please.

Comment: `SELECT log.*, users.user_rank, users.user_id
 FROM ( SELECT * FROM chat WHERE post_roomid = '$room' AND post_id > '$last' $query_add ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 60) AS log , users
 WHERE log.post_uid = users.user_id
 ORDER BY post_id ASC`

i found that this query is working exactly like i want but it seem to be a join and it do not get data if the users table return empty but i would like to have it as a left join to return empty field even if there is no match from the users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inverted order you use

```
SELECT log.*, users.user_rank, users.user_id 
FROM ( SELECT * 
            FROM `chat` 
            WHERE `post_roomid` = '$room' 
            AND post_id > '$last' 
            AND user_id != $uid" 
            ORDER BY `post_id` DESC
             LIMIT 60) AS log 
LEFT  JOIN user log.user_id = user.user_id
ORDER BY log.`post_id` ASC
```

Comment: the order i got at this time is the right order it show in the order i need your way will show inverse of my current query and that is not what im looking for im looking to join data from user table with my actual query.

Comment: I have update the answer .. with a join with user table

Comment: that do not work is it because my user table have user_id and my chat table have also user_id to compare ?

Comment: I have update the answer ... but if the problem is only change the name of ia column  you could do this easly ......

Comment: `SELECT log.*, users.user_rank, users.user_id
 FROM ( SELECT * FROM chat WHERE post_roomid = '$room' AND post_id > '$last' $query_add ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 60) AS log , users
 WHERE log.post_uid = users.user_id
 ORDER BY post_id ASC`



i found that this query is working exactly like i want but it seem to be a join and it do not get data if the users table return empty but i would like to have it as a left join to return empty field even if there is no match from the users table.

Comment: I congratulate you for your efforts, if you liked what I did, you can also mark my answer as helpful answer

Comment: well is easy on the top left of each answer there are  two arrow:  up arrow is for flag as useful  .. down arrow is for unuseful or wrong .. answer .. .. clicking on up arrow you give +10 to the answer poster ...click on down arrow you give -2 to answer poster and -1 to you.. hope is all clear ..

Comment: really i thank you of course i was trying and trying for last 3 day cause i hate to ask for answer i think trying is the best way to learn and remember but you your first answer even if it was not working for me changed my way to use sql query thanks again.

Comment: Just for curiosity .. how long are you using sql?

Comment: SQL is powerful but it is not easy to understand .. reason according to set theory is not spontaneous...  anyway ... good luck and good work